# VMware clarity hamburger menu

Tags: vmware-clarity

I have been trying to use Clarity v1.0. It seems that the burger menu does not appear when the side menu collapses. Looking at the documentation I could not find anything that refers to this.

Is there anything that we need to configure to make it work?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you have a demo of what you're trying to do so we can better understand what you're doing?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I was not using the right components.

Answer (score 0):

Looking through this more thoroughly, I needed to use the clr-main-container, clr-header components.

The relevant documentation, in case somebody ends up here can be found:

https://clarity.design/documentation/navigation#responsive_navigation

> Note: Responsive navigation requires you to use the following Angular components to build the layout of your application: 
>   clr-main-container
>   clr-header